# How to design 1D CNN in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, conv-neural-network

I am new to matlab and my project requires 1D Convolutional Neural Network. Can anyone tell me how to design `1D` CNN in [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab)?
 Does it require any special hardware? Refrence to some blogs will be really helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: The best thing you can do is take a look at the [matlab documentation](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/nnet/convolutional-neural-networks.html) or [an example](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/nnet/examples/create-simple-deep-learning-network-for-classification.html). Depending on your current knowledge, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network) may be very helpful too.

Answer (score -2):

As I know CNN implementation requires GPU. Matlab 2016 version have some inbuilt function but requires GPU installed to work. Python and tensorflow works great and quick , I would like you suggest to try those than Matlab.

Comment: From the [MATLAB documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/convolutional-neural-networks.html) linked in the comment above, "You can train a convolutional neural network on either a CPU, a GPU, or multiple GPUs and/or in parallel." So it seems that MATLAB's CNN implementation does **not** require a GPU. Otherwise, this is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Sorry, Stackflow doesnt allow me to add comment. I havent checked the documentation, but I tried working with Matlab at first but it give me error GPU is missing! so as in comment.

Comment: Yes, you need 50 reputation to comment on other people's posts. I would suggest that you wait until you have 50 rep to comment rather than posting answers that aren't answers, and incorrect ones at that.